# When should add padding to struct in LLVM IR? And When shouldn't?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Clang has different behaviors in different cases, when add padding to struct, and what's the rule?

For below c++ code:

```cpp
struct CT1 {
  char   c1 = 'c';
  double d1;
  char   c2;
};

struct CT2 {
  char   c1;
  double d1;
  char   c2;
};
struct CT3 {
  char   c1 = 'c';
  double d1;
};

int main() {
  CT1 ct1;
  CT2 ct2;
  CT3 ct3;
  return 0;
}
```

Clang will generate IR code:

```cpp
%struct.CT1 = type <{ i8, [7 x i8], double, i8, [7 x i8] }>
%struct.CT2 = type { i8, double, i8 }
%struct.CT3 = type { i8, double }
```

---

I have several questions:

1. CT1 has padding, while CT2 has not. CT1 is only different with CT2 by having a initial value of `c1`. Why?
2. CT3 hasn't padding, which is only different with CT1 by reduced a property named `c2`. Why?
3. IR Code of CT2 doesn't add padding explicitly, but in log (using `-Wpadded`) it seems to have added padding already, is this true? And does it means that we can not add padding by hand?

```sh
warning: padding struct 'CT3' with 7 bytes to align 'd1' [-Wpadded]
  double d1;
```

4. How to add padding to struct by IRBuilder of LLVM?

I need to generate IR code by hand, so i need to know when should i add padding to struct.

Really thanks for any reply.

Comment: CT1 has a custom constructor while CT2 does not. This makes CT1 non-POD, unlike CT2. It seems that these are treated differently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837373/standard-layout-and-tail-padding As for 3: I think you simply add fake i8 fields manually?

Comment: Clang has C++ rules and target machine rules. The former is not my cup of tea. For the latter, LLVM's target layout declaration decides when pushing is/needs to be added.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for reply. i8 fields of CT3 is really added by mistake, had deleted it.

Comment: @arnt Thanks for reply. I really need to find out the rules clearly.

Comment: C++ is not known for simple rules. Making life simple for compiler authors is/was an explicit non-goal. Sorry. But at least you have the clang source and can read it.